# angular tab selection opens new page instead of open in the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

How to display the tab selection results in same page?

I have stacked 3 tabs in my page and the resulting html pages are loaded in new page instead of loading in the same page.

I followed the below sample and its working fine till the part its explained.
https://codepen.io/jasoncluck/pen/iDcbh

I have mentioned my URL path in href attribute of anchor tag.
Ex:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked nav-pills" role="tablist">
    <li ng-class="{'active': view_tab == 'tab1'}">
        <a class="btn-lg" ng-click="changeTab('tab1')" href="/tabl">Tab1</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="{'active': view_tab == 'tab2'}">
        <a class="btn-lg" ng-click="changeTab('tab2')" href="/tab2">Tab2</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="{'active': view_tab == 'tab3'}">
        <a class="btn-lg" ng-click="changeTab('tab2')" href="/tab3"> Tab3 </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and below is my router part

```
    .when('/tabl', {
        controller : 'URLController',
        templateUrl : './views/URL.html'
    })
```

I can see my controller and templateURL is loaded but in the different page.
If not possible with href then please share me ideas to follow.

Comment: i dont find `routeprovider` in your codepen example

Comment: Yes.. instead of displaying the plain text i m routing to new URL...

Comment: show your code along with `routeprovider`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<div ui-view></div>` is the rescuer...

This will render the child state inside your parent state template.

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('TabController', function () {
        this.tab = 1;

        this.setTab = function (tabId) {
            this.tab = tabId;
        };

        this.isSet = function (tabId) {
            return this.tab === tabId;
        };
    });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container" ng-app="myApp">
<br/><br/><br/>
<h1 align="center">AngularJs Tab Example</h1>
    <section ng-controller="TabController as tab">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li ng-class="{active:tab.isSet(1)}"><a href ng-click="tab.setTab(1)">Tab 1</a></li>
            <li ng-class="{active:tab.isSet(2)}"><a href ng-click="tab.setTab(2)">Tab 2</a></li>
            <li ng-class="{active:tab.isSet(3)}"><a href ng-click="tab.setTab(3)">Tab 3</a></li>
    <li ng-class="{active:tab.isSet(4)}"><a href ng-click="tab.setTab(4)">Tab 4</a></li>
    <li ng-class="{active:tab.isSet(5)}"><a href ng-click="tab.setTab(5)">Tab 5</a></li>
    <li ng-class="{active:tab.isSet(6)}"><a href ng-click="tab.setTab(6)">Tab 6</a></li>
    <li ng-class="{active:tab.isSet(7)}"><a href ng-click="tab.setTab(7)">Tab 7</a></li>
     <li ng-class="{active:tab.isSet(8)}"><a href ng-click="tab.setTab(8)">Tab 8</a></li>
        </ul>
        <hr>
        <div ng-show="tab.isSet(1)">
             <h4>Tab 1</h4>
    <h6> Description of Tab 1</h6>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="tab.isSet(2)">
             <h4>Tab 2</h4>
    <h6> Description of Tab 2</h6>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="tab.isSet(3)">
             <h4>Tab 3</h4>
    <h6> Description of Tab 3</h6>
        </div>
   <div ng-show="tab.isSet(4)">
             <h4>Tab 4</h4>
    <h6> Description of Tab 4</h6>
        </div>
   <div ng-show="tab.isSet(5)">
             <h4>Tab 5</h4>
    <h6> Description of Tab 5</h6>
        </div>
   <div ng-show="tab.isSet(6)">
             <h4>Tab 6</h4>
    <h6> Description of Tab 6</h6>
        </div>
   <div ng-show="tab.isSet(7)">
             <h4>Tab 7</h4>
    <h6> Description of Tab 7</h6>
        </div>
   <div ng-show="tab.isSet(8)">
             <h4>Tab 8</h4>
    <h6> Description of Tab 8</h6>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

[Demo Tab](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yVpPwrRD5iM)